# Crazy CSS Issue in Firefox Only - position fixed and background color

Tags: html, css, firefox

See this link:

http://lsp2.tpdserver2.co.uk/test.htm

Displays fine in IE/Chrome but in Firefox (6.0.1) there is a 1px border around the blue header.

If I add a background color to the #header-content, the 1px white border dissapears. This seems crazy.

I cannot work out what is going on with this and the related page I am trying to build depends on not having a background colour for the 2nd fixed container.

Here is an image of the problem I see:

[Link to Image](http://lsp2.tpdserver2.co.uk/ff-problem.jpg)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in FF 6.0.1

Comment: Are you sure? Use firebug to set the background color of the #header-content and watch the blue box properly line up top left. I have tried on 2 different computers running FF6.0.1

Comment: I can reproduce it. No idea how to fix it, though. [I'd suggest filing a bug for it.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: Just installed FF 6 and firebug fresh. Not seeing the border you described. Might be something unique to your development environment.

Comment: Added an image to show what is going on.

Comment: You've not got a non-zero page zoom level set in your Firefox, have you? I've seen odd 1-pixel-off rendering errors caused by that in the past.

Comment: Tried reset of zoom level - no joy.

Comment: Searching for solution of my own problem i stumbled upon your question, @Simon. Unfortunately, it's unusable as links are broken.

Comment: Even this is an old thread, I've been dealing with this in FF19.0.2 in OSX. Using opacity opacity:0.9999999; it got fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is layout rendering bug in Firefox. This bug was already reported and as I know it is fixed in next release. Only solution I know is to use `opacity:0.9999999`. It would render correctly as opacity:1, but fix this annoying bug.

Try `#header { opacity:0.9999999; }`

[Bugzilla : Bug 677095](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677095)

**EDIT: Firefox 8 is not affected with this bug and setting opacity to 0.9999999 will result in weird border around the element, so I prefer not to use it anymore**

Comment: This works for the test page I put up thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work for my actual site (which has a much more complicated layout but suffers the same issue).

Comment: Scratch that it works for my page too, you need the exact number of zeros! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Browsers add different defaults if you don't "reset" the CSS, that may be what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

If the `z-index` value of your `#header-content` is *not greater* than 10, then the bug is fixed. If it's 11 or greater then I can see the mysterious gap too.

Really weird.

Comment: Actually it seems it is related the the z-index of the second container. If you make the second container z-index less than the first the problem goes away. I don't know if this will help my actual webpage yet but it should still not occur.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce in FF 6.0.1; however, you can probably work around this with

`background-color: transparent;`

on the #header-content, or white if you don't want it being see through.

This should still give the fix you mentioned while remaining a blank div as required.

**Update:**

Ok thanks for the screenshot, still cannot reproduce, this time with ff 6.0.2 - I had a look around after noticing I can reproduce a similar issue on different zoom levels.

[Blog post](http://markasunread.com/2009/06/zoom-bug-in-ie78-and-firefox-caused-by-border/) explaining the zoom border bug, which includes this [test page](http://markasunread.com/examples/zoombug.html). I am not sure if this is involved, seems similar but not the same thing, zoom bug will take off a slice of the whole page including the border of #header-content.

As for your comments around transparent, you can use it and still supply a background image, does this not work for you?

Comment: I stated this fixed it in my question. This is the problem though because on my real page this container needs a background image - and therefore it is broken.

Comment: Disabled all addons still get the same issue. It is very sutble, I have added an image to the question showing it.

Comment: Thanks Louis. Transparent bg doesn't seem to work only fixed color. Also z-index influences it. I raised it as a bug on Firefox and some discussion there seems to relate it to another bug which as far as I can understand may have some relation to actual gfx card drivers. Maybe that is why only some people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hmm that is quite the out there bug. I'll have to have a look at home on a few different PC's. - If you really wanted to try you could attempt it with a solid color and css filter it to be transparent (different from transparent color setting I'm hoping). Really grasping for something there though!