# Firefox background-attachment: fixed Nightmare

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have been pulling my hair out on this one all day, and I'm hoping someone smarter than me can figure it out.

I'm working on a new design for my site, and I've run into what appears to be a Firefox bug. I am using background-attachment: fixed for a gradient on the `<body>` element and then I have a full width `<div>` with another background image at the top of the page. Only in Firefox, there is a small white border at the top of the page and on either side of the `<div>` background.

I've tried at least a half-dozen different ways of coding the HTML and CSS, and they all produce the same results. Also, the white gap doesn't appear to be there in earlier versions of Firefox (I noticed it in version 6). I even did a clean reinstall of Firefox without any add-ons, and I'm still seeing it. Any ideas on what's causing this? Is my code wrong in some way?

See simplified test case here: http://mygemologist.com/bg-fixed-test.html

Note: This question may be related to: [Crazy CSS Issue in Firefox Only - position fixed and background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310518/crazy-css-issue-in-firefox-only-position-fixed-and-background-color), but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset of some kind?

Comment: There's no problem in Firefox 6 for me. Have you confirmed this bug on anyone else's machine?

Comment: I'm also not seeing any issue in Firefox 6, like @da5id.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The only CSS reset I'm using is the universal 0 margin and padding. I have confirmed the bug on 2 machines so far, both running Firefox 6 on Windows 7. Would it be helpful if I posted a screen capture of how it's rendering for me?

Comment: Confirmed the same issue on a 3rd machine (Vista). This time, I checked that it was rendering correctly on Firefox 5 (it was) and then updated to v6 and saw the same issue. I have also updated the test case with a screen capture highlighting the problem for clarity.

Comment: Does the problem disappear if you turn off hardware acceleration?  If so, it sounds like a known bug in Firefox 6 in some Windows configurations; a fix for it should be shipping in Firefox 8, I believe.

Comment: @Boris, The problem does disappear when I turn off hardware acceleration. Thank you so much for figuring that out. So, it is a Firefox bug. Does anyone know of any work-arounds for this?

Comment: @Dominic At a guess this is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677095 and in particular, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677095#c47

Comment: @Boris, that did it! I don't think I'm allowed to accept a comment as the solution, but that was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dominic added the comment as an answer so other people see it more easily too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dominic, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677095 for this issue and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677095#c47 for a possible workaround.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310518/crazy-css-issue-in-firefox-only-position-fixed-and-background-color/7389005#7389005

Comment: @Boris, up for round 2? It seems the hardware acceleration bug hasn't gone away in Firefox 8. It's gotten worse. The opacity hack has pretty much no effect now. Do you know of another way to disable hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Dominic I don't know offhand.  Can you please file a bug with a testcase and add ":bz" to the cc list?  I'll make sure someone familiar with Windows graphics stuff looks...

Comment: @BorisZbarsky, ok, I filled the bug as you suggested. Just for reference, the bug is here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701528

Comment: @Dominic Thanks for filing that!

Comment: @Boris, I just wanted to say thank you for pointing me in the right direction, and helping to resolve this. I've been so impressed with the Firefox devs on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a smaller width image? It seems firefox has issues rendering it, when zooming it goes from properly displayed to having a 1-2px white border above it.

EDIT

When I change the body css to background-position: scroll the problem seems to go away

```
body {
  background: url("http://www.mygemologist.com/resources/bg-gradient.jpg") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
}
```

Comment: I too have noticed the zooming phenomenon. Just so I understand you right. Are you suggesting a smaller width image for the `<body>` background or the `<div>` background?

Comment: Yes, the problem is only with background-attachment: **fixed**, unfortunately that's the look I'm trying to create with this design.