# jQuery Animation Breaks on Version 1.7

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jQuery, and I was wondering if someone could offer me some guidance as to why my animation just broke when I updated to jQuery 1.7.0. As you can see from the example (http://jsfiddle.net/jhpvc/), the accordion works perfectly with jQuery 1.6.4, but if you change it to 1.7, it fails completely.

P.S. If you view it on Firefox 8 with hardware acceleration enabled, you might see some strange flickering. This is a separate issue, but if you have any ideas how to mitigate that as well I am all ears (see [Firefox background-attachment: fixed Nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328132/firefox-background-attachment-fixed-nightmare/7350095#7350095))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in jQuery 1.7 - animating with percentages isn't working properly... [ticket #10669](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10669).

Comment: thank you so much for figuring that out. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: It also wasn't working with animating em's, but it's also fixed in 1.7.1